# String.methods.include?(:upcase) => false but '.upcase' is listed in ruby-doc.org

Tags: ruby, string, api

I have been playing around with Strings a bit (in irb), and found myself in trouble understanding the meaning of the following code:

```
String.methods
=> [:try_convert, :allocate, :new, :superclass, :freeze, :===, :==, :<=>, :<, :<=, :>,
:>=, :to_s, :included_modules, :include?, :name, :ancestors, :instance_methods, 
:public_instance_methods, :protected_instance_methods, :private_instance_methods, 
:constants, :const_get, :const_set, :const_defined?, :const_missing, :class_variables, 
:remove_class_variable, :class_variable_get, :class_variable_set, 
:class_variable_defined?, :public_constant, :private_constant, :module_exec, :class_exec, 
:module_eval, :class_eval, :method_defined?, :public_method_defined?, 
:private_method_defined?, :protected_method_defined?, :public_class_method, 
:private_class_method, :autoload, :autoload?, :instance_method, :public_instance_method, 
:nil?, :=~, :!~, :eql?, :hash, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :initialize_dup, 
:initialize_clone, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :frozen?, 
:inspect, :methods, :singleton_methods, :protected_methods, :private_methods, 
:public_methods, :instance_variables, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, 
:instance_variable_defined?, :instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :send, :public_send, 
:respond_to?, :respond_to_missing?, :extend, :display, :method, :public_method, 
:define_singleton_method, :object_id, :to_enum, :enum_for, :equal?, :!, :!=, 
:instance_eval, :instance_exec, :__send__, :__id__]
```

Hence the well-known method 'upcase' was not included in the output, i tried to receive it this way:

```
String.methods.include?(:upcase)
=> false                          # mother of god, I am shocked!
```

But http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-upcase lists the .upcase method as a method of the Class String.

And of course, in my irb-sessions or the Editor, ruby understands perfectly to execute

```
"whatdoiknow".upcase
=> "WHATDOIKNOW"
```

My Questions are:

1. What kind of methods is this output from String.methods
2. Why is the .upcase method not listed in this output
3. How can i literally list all methods for String (eg. when I am searching for something)

Comment: `String.instance_methods.include? :upcase` == `true`

Comment: String.instance_methods, you are listing clss methods

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strings have an `upcase` method. But `String` is not a string, it is a *class*, and classes don't have an `upcase` method.

If you want to know whether a particular string object has an `upcase` method, you should ask that string:

```
'foo'.methods.include?(:upcase) # => true
```

Or you should ask the `String` class whether it has an instance method `include` defined for all strings:

```
String.instance_methods.include?(:upcase) # => true
```

Remember: classes are objects just like any other. They have methods, they have instance variables, they have a class.

Comment: That's a good explanation, but `respond_to?(:upcase)` is almost always a better idea than `methods.include?(:upcase)` since some classes will create methods on demand and have a customized `respond_to?` implementation that accounts for this. It's a mistake to expect all methods are explicitly listed.

Comment: @tadman: Yes, whether an object responds to a specific message and whether an object has a specific method are two different questions. Usually, an object will react to a message by invoking a method of the same name as the message, but that is not always the case. The OP was asking about method, not messages, though, so I answered about methods.

Answer (score 5):

`String.methods` refers to methods on the `String` class; `"foo".methods` refers to methods on an *instance* of the `String` class.

In fact, the documentation that you linked to does show `upcase` under the "Public Instance Methods" heading.

Answer (score 3):

You should write :

```
String.instance_methods.include? :upcase
```

Another way to look back which is instance method and which is method of String as an example here:(Just notice the `#` symbole and `.` symbol)

```
String.new.method(:upcase) #=> #<Method: String#upcase>
String.method(:try_convert) #=> #<Method: String.try_convert>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `upcase` method is an instance method, not a class method.

Look at the difference between `String.methods` and `"string".methods`

```
"whatdoiknow".methods.include?(:upcase)
=> true
```